# How can i create a application in opendaylight using the nitrogen archtype

Tags: opendaylight

I'm noticed that the steps to create a new application using the archtype:generate command is creating a carbon distribution, i want to create a application  that will run in the newst release, nitrogen.

I had a problem before ([How to import other opendaylight projects in my own odl distro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48272665/how-to-import-other-opendaylight-projects-in-my-own-odl-distro)) and a good guy said to me that the OpenDaylight that i was using seemed to be the carbon release.

In the -DarchtypeVersion parameter i'm using the 1.3.3-SNAPSHOT value, i also tested other versions but nothing of them seems be the Nitrogen, so there's a way to create applications in the newst version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nitrogen version is 1.4.2-SNAPSHOT.